# Use variables in in JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json

I want to use variables to get a specific value from my JSON.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  var jsonContent = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

  var day = mon;
  var name = abc;

  var restaurants = jsonContent.name.table.day;
```

The variables "day" and "name" will be different everytime the code starts because I need different values from my JSON.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Use bracket notation: `jsonContent[name]['table'][day]`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets

Comment: FYI, after the `JSON.parse`, you are no longer dealing with JSON, you have a JavaScript Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get values with property string like this

```
var restaurants = jsonContent[name].table[day]
```

Comment: This one works. Just needed to change "var day = mon;" and "var name = abc;" to string values.

Thanks!